# Parametrising a dictionary print statement

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

I am experimenting with changing the parameters of an XHR request to change the contents of the dictionary object returned. Looking at this code as a starting point:

```
teamStatDicts = responser[u'teamTableStats']
    for statDict in teamStatDicts:

    print("{seasonId},{tournamentRegionId},{minsPlayed},"
    "{tournamentId},".decode('cp1252').format(**statDict))
```

In this example responser is a .json() object returned which contains the various dictionary objects generated by the XHR requests. A typical response with the code above would appear as so:

```
9155,5,900
9155,5,820
...
...
...
9155,5,900
9155,5,820
```

When the parameters of the XHR requests are changed, certain dictionary items will always be constant (such as the ones in the above example), however some will change depending on what parameters are used.

So as not to have to use numerous print statements, I would like to assign some of the dictionary keys in the print statement to variables that will change within a `for loop`. I'm ok with how to code all the loops up, but I am unsure how I could use variables in the above print statement.

For testing purposes, I would just manually assign the variable values like so:

```
var1 = "yellowCard"
var2 = "redCard"
```

I've thought of maybe something like this as a solution:

```
teamStatDicts = responser[u'teamTableStats']
        for statDict in teamStatDicts:

        mynewvar = ("{seasonId},{tournamentRegionId},{minsPlayed},{",var1,"},{",var2,"},"
        "{tournamentId},".decode('cp1252').format(**statDict))

        mynewvar = str(''.join(mynewvar[0:5]))
        print newvar
```

I'm not sure that looks very viable syntax wise though. My code has a lot of nested loops to accommodate various combinations of parameters, so before I start chopping it up I was wondering whether the above will work and if not if someone could suggest an alternative syntax?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like you want to be able to construct the *format string* for your print statement in a progromattic way. In that case, would not something like the following do the job?

```
def print_json(keys, stat_dict, decode_format = 'cp1252'):
    '''
    :type keys: [str,...]
    :param keys: The list of key names to include from the stat_ditc
    '''
    fstring = ','.join('{{{}}}'.format(key) for key in keys)
    print(fstring.decode(decode_format).format(**stat_dict))
```

Usage:

```
>>> print_json(['seasonId','tournamentRegionId'], statsDict)
'9155,5'
>>> print_json(['seasonId','tournamentRegionId','minsPlayed'], statsDict)
'9155,5,900'
```

Then it's just a matter of using the right key-set at the right time.